# There's a Localhost error when I am fetching data from stapi through api

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api, localhost, strapi

This is the code

[image: 1]

code:

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import Card from "../Card/Card";
import "./Featuredproducts.scss";
import axios from "axios";

function Featuredproducts({ type }) {
// Fetching Data From API
  const [products, setProducts] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchData = async () => {
      try {
        const data = await axios.get(
          process.env.REACT_APP_API_URL + "/products",
          {
            headers: {
              Authorization: "bearer" + process.env.REACT_APP_API_TOKKEN,
            },
          }
        );
        console.log(data);
      } catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
      }
    };
    fetchData();
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className="featuredProducts">
      <div className="top">
        <h1>{type} products</h1>
        <p>
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Neque
          laudantium similique laborum sequi dolores quam qui ullam, obcaecati
          placeat tempora distinctio voluptatum repellat veritatis minima beatae
          recusandae, necessitatibus alias esse quisquam eaque harum vero vel?
        </p>
      </div>
      <div className="bottom">
        {data.map((item) => (
          <Card item={item} key={item.id} />
        ))}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Featuredproducts;
```

I have given Strapi localhost api address and even key too.
Error:
[This is the that i am getting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KuMRE.png)
if anyone know the problem please help me out

If i am not wrong i think the problem is with local host server address
just incase i have given this url through env file

```
REACT_APP_API_URL = http://localhost:1337/api
```

Comment: As you can see in error, your endpoint includes `undefined`.

Answer (score 0):

It seems your api path is incorrect. First of all, check your REACT_APP_API_URL is correct. to do that, you can simply log to console

```js
console.log(process.env.REACT_APP_API_URL)
```

I think its the problem here

Otherwise, you have to type the axios url directly.

```js
const fetchData = async () => {
      try {
        const data = await axios.get(
          "http://localhost:1337/api/products",
          {
            headers: {
              Authorization: "bearer" + process.env.REACT_APP_API_TOKKEN,
            },
          }
        );
        console.log(data);
      } catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
      }
    };
```

For Best practice **Define Your Functions Outside From UseEffect**